# How set local variable to a type which was passed in as method parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'm new to Java generics and I'm trying to set a local variable to a passed in type. The passed-in type extends the custom class Model:

Something as follows:

```
public void myMethod(<T extends Model> MyType){

    MyType item = (MyType)getObjectFromStore();

}
```

Where MyType could be of class Model or its sub-classes.

Is this possible in Java? I appreciate any pointers in the right direction. I realize this is probably a basic question but I can't seem to find the right way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define  `myMethod` as this:

```
public <T extends Model> void myMethod(T myType) {
..
}
```

which says that the method parameter(`myType`) could be of type `Model` or its subclasses.

Comment: @PierreRymiortz Note that there's no point it using generics here, since the method doesn't return `T` and no other parameters are bound by it (for example `List<T>`). Just declare `public void myMethod(Model myType)`. Although it's unclear what you're actually doing with `getObjectFromStore()` etc.